# Append array inside object using $set (props doesn't get updated)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object and the structure looks like this

```
obj: {
  1: {
    'a': [ [] ],
    'b': [ [] ]
  }
}
```

Now, in watcher, I am trying to append `'c' => [ [] ]` to this object.

- I tried using `this.obj[1]['c'] = [ [] ]`, but it doesn't watch changes on the props (on child component) when I do it this way. I am almost sure that I need to use `$set`
- `this.$set(this.obj, 1, { ['c']: [ [] ] })` - using this actually watches it, however it removes 'a' and 'b' properties entirely.
- Using `this.$set(this.obj[1], ['c'], [ [] ]);` - seems like changing the object however props doesn't watch this either

What is the proper way of using $set

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `this.$set(this.obj['1'], 'c', [[]])`? Not sure why you would try and use an array (ie `['c']`) as the object key

Comment: Using this, it updates the object properly on the props, however the DOM doesn't get updated :/ If I use `{{ obj }}` before running for loops, it still doesnt

Comment: Please show an example of this

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, simply use

```
this.$set(this.obj['1'], 'c', [[]])
```

For example...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    obj: {
      1: {
        'a': [ [] ],
        'b': [ [] ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addC: function() {
      this.$set(this.obj['1'], 'c', [[]])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p><button @click="addC">Add "c" property</button>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(prop, key) in obj">
        {{ key }}
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(arr, letter) in prop">
            {{ letter }} - size: {{ arr.length }}
            <ul>
              <li v-for="(sub, idx) in arr">
                Index {{ idx }} - size: {{ sub.length }}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried on fiddle too :/ it is working as expected, but in my project, for some reason, it doesn't work as expected. It is updating the object, I can see in vue debugger however it doesn't update the DOM. Using `{{ obj }}` also gives same result :/